# Guardian.Plug.current_resource is nil

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using Guardian and Ueberauth for my authentication but something weird is happening. `Guardian.Plug.authenticated?(conn)` returns `true` but `Guardian.Plut.current_resource(conn)` returns `false`. I am also using `Guardian.Phoenix.Controller` and `current_user` is `nil`, but `Guardian.Plug.EnsureAuthenticated` is giving me access.

Comment: Can you post the source of your SessionController (or whatever controller calls `Guardian.Plug.sign_in`)?

Comment: Of course. This isn't my project but my current auth_controller is exactly the same. https://github.com/hassox/phoenix_guardian/blob/ueberauth-guardian/web/controllers/auth_controller.ex

Comment: After a quick glance at Guardian's source, I think the only way `current_resource` can return `false` is if you passed `false` as the "object" (2nd argument) to `sign_in`. Can you check the values you're passing to `sign_in`?

Comment: I just confirmed that this behavior only happens after I reset the database. Everything works fine when I sign_in or sign_out.

Comment: I still don't understand why the browser has access to restricted path when the `current_user` is `nil` after `mix ecto.reset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening because I was missing `hooks: GuardianDb`in the Guardian configuration.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I wish you'd explain why you needed the `hooks: GuardianDb` and how you configured it.